# How to make actionlink/url.action in kendo-ui grid

Tags: javascript, jquery, asp.net-mvc-4, kendo-ui, kendo-asp.net-mvc

currently i am working in asp.net mvc5 project on kendo-ui grid...

I want to know if there is possibility of making action link or url.action in grid where grid button lies....

```
<script>
    $(document).ready(function () {
        var projectdata = "http://localhost:xxxx",
        $("#grid").kendoGrid({
            dataSource: dataSource,
            pageable: true,
            toolbar: ["create"],
            scrollable: false,
            sortable: true,
            groupable: true,
            columns: [
                { field: "Name", title: "Task Name", width: "170px" },
                { field: "Status", title: "Status", width: "110px" },
                { field: "IsActive", title: "Active", width: "50px" },
                { command: ["edit", "delete", "Setting", "Task"], title: "&nbsp;", width: "150px" }
            ],
            editable: "popup"
        });
    });
</script>
```

I have to change "Setting" in Command field and put action link or url.action there.

Comment: can i do this like @Html.ActionLink("Setting", "Home", "ProjectContr", new { orderId = id },null)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Create a custom command template:

```
    <script id="command-template" type="text/x-kendo-template">
            <a class="k-button k-grid-even" href=" @Html.ActionLink("Setting", "Home", "ProjectContr", new { orderId = id },null)">Even</a>
    </script>
```

and add it as part of your columns

```
columns: [
    { field: "Name", title: "Task Name", width: "170px" },
    { field: "Status", title: "Status", width: "110px" },
    { field: "IsActive", title: "Active", width: "50px" },
    { command: ["edit", "delete", "Setting", "Task"], title: "&nbsp;", width: "150px" },
    { template: kendo.template($("#command-template").html())}]
```

Know that this will work only if the code is part of the cshtml file as the like needs to be parsed. The link will fail if its separated to a js file.

Answer (score 3):

if you are using asp.net mvc why not use the razor code?

heres a example, hope it helps

```
                @(Html.Kendo().Grid<YourObject>()
                            .Name("grid")
                            .TableHtmlAttributes(new { style = "min-height: 331px;" })                                             
                            .ToolBar(t => t.Create())
                            .Columns(columns =>
                            {
                                columns.Template(@<text></text>).ClientTemplate("<div style=\"text-align:center\">" +
                                                                                "<a href=\"" +  Url.Action("Test", new { id = "#=Id#"}) + "\"><i style=\"padding-right: 8px;\" title=\"Setting\" class=\"fa fa-pencil fa-lg\"></i></a>" +

                                                                                "</div>").Width(60).Title("");
                                columns.Bound(c=>c.Id).Hidden(true);
                                columns.Bound(c=>c.Name);
                                columns.Bound(c => c.Status);
                                columns.Bound(c => c.IsActive).ClientTemplate("<div style=\"text-align:center\">" +
                                                                               "# if(Active) {#" +
                                                                               "yes" +
                                                                               "#} else {#" +
                                                                               "no" +
                                                                               "#}#" +
                                                                               "</div>").Width(15);                                    

                            })                                
                            .Sortable()
                            .Filterable()
                            .Pageable()
                            .DataSource(dataSource => dataSource
                                .Ajax()
                                .Model(model => model.Id(m => m.Id))
                                .Read(read => read.Action("Read", "YourObject"))
                             )
                            ).Filterable()
                        )
```

Comment: thanks for reply, upvote for the answer although i have found solution

Comment: That's a really neat trick how you passed the ID into the Url Action. Never would have guessed that was possible! Thank you.